# Alternate chapter style

Tags: chapters, fncychap

I wonder how to make this chapter style.
[image]

Currently, I am using this style.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{Cerulean}}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a small compilable code, and explain what is not as you want?

Comment: I don't have a small compilable code, instead i have the full latex document of thesis. I want to change the default chapter style.

Comment: Can't you extract the necessary code to obtain a compilable document? You don't what is you document class, which packages you load, &c. Do you want a sans font for your chapter titles, as the image seems to suggest?

Comment: I answered my own question. But what font family should I use?

Comment: In the first argument, insert `\sffamily` instead of `\normalfont`, and delete it from the second argument.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I achieved what I want.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
[display]
  {\LARGE\sffamily\bf\color{Black}}
  {\color{blue}\Large CHAPTER \thechapter}
  {0.5em}{}
```

[image]